# Get rid of a preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to completely get rid of a preference? It seems that clear() and remove(key) doesn't get rid of the preference completely. If you call clear() then call SharedPreferences.contains("key"), it returns true.

Note that I do also commit() the clear().

Comment: It would be easier if we could see some of your code.  By calling clear and then commit should work.  It sounds like the commands are not being called.

Comment: The commands are being called. The issue is that the VALUE is cleared, but the property/key that I define still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how `clear()` implemented:

```
public Editor clear() {
    synchronized (this) {
        mClear = true;
        return this;
    }
}

public boolean commit() {
    //...    
    synchronized (this) {
      if (mClear) {
        mMap.clear();
        mClear = false;
      }
    }
    //...
}
```

Here is how `contains(String key)` implemented:

```
 public boolean contains(String key) {
   synchronized (this) {
     return mMap.containsKey(key);
   }
 }
```

You can see code yourself [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#0EoX9IQXwTc/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java&q=SharedPreferencesImpl&sa=N&cd=5&ct=rc&l=173). (Note that preference change listeners are not called when all preferences are cleared).

The implementation looks fine to me, and most likely that it's problem with your code. 
Here is my short example application which verifies that `clear()` works correctly.

```
public class TestPrefClear extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("TEST", true).commit();
        if(!prefs.contains("TEST")){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        prefs.edit().clear().commit();
        if(prefs.contains("TEST")){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`clear()` is ambiguous, it first clear the preferences,then reinitialize with the modified `preference. replace()` could meet your need,just pass an empty map to it.

Comment: is there documentation for replace()? I can't find it

Comment: oh, it's an internal api. I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Function `replace()` is not placed in the SharedPreferences interface, but this function exists in SharedPreferencesImpl implementation of SharedPreferences. I'd recommend avoid using it.